# Output DAX Evaluate results to a SQL Server Database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssas, dax

So I have a DAX query that I have built in SSAS. But since my application like DAX, I thought pushing the set of DAX results to a database server table would be the ideal solution for my application to read.

How do I output the contents of a DAX query to a SQL Server database table? And if possible truncate the contents of the table before each run?

I'm using SQL Server 2016 if that helps.

Comment: This is a very important question that seems to not have been addressed yet. My idea is that you would need some kind of orchestrator able to launch a DAX query on SSAS and write the result into a CSV or another DataBase.

Comment: Yep so you can get dax editor to output the results to CSV and get SQL to read from there. Not ideal, since this is an extra step.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using a linked server to output the contents of an 'open query' to a table variable in SQL.